# Cannot connect to Wifi with WPA2 AES Encryption Security

Tags: wireless, security

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I am having a problem in connecting to the Router with WPA2 Security with AES Encryption. I am able to connect to that Router using my cellphone, Windows PC but my Ubuntu machine cannot connect.

Does Ubuntu support AES encryption for Wifi Devices?

Previously when I was using Ubuntu 10.10 there was no problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed the issue.

Reboot > "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" > Chose a different Linux kernel > Booted into Ubuntu > Performed System Updates > Reboot > Boot into Ubuntu as normal.

That seemed to work for me.

Comment: I did update the packages everytime to make it work. Its happening for all the kernels I have installed in my machine. I think its a bug that disables connecting to wifi with wpa2 AES security